# get table without Added column in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Process table in sql server database like this:

[image: Process Table]

I need to select `Process` if `Rolename` exists in to `RoleTable` like this:

```
 select ID,WorkflowXML 
    from 
    (
    select m.c.value('@RoleName','nvarchar(max)') as Rolename,p.*
    from Process as p
    outer apply p.WorkflowXML.nodes('/workflow/Tasks/Task[@type="start"]/TaskUsers/TaskUser') as m(c)
    ) as Pro where Pro.Rolename in
    (SELECT * from RoleTable)
```

In this select `Rolename` adds to `Process`. I need to only `Process` table. I can add `Process` fields (`ID,WorkflowXML`) to query. If I change `Process` table design I should edit query. This is not very good.

Is there a way to select `Process` table in query without adding `Process` fields like this?

```
select Pro
        from 
        (
        select m.c.value('@RoleName','nvarchar(max)') as Rolename,p.*
        from Process as p
        outer apply p.WorkflowXML.nodes('/workflow/Tasks/Task[@type="start"]/TaskUsers/TaskUser') as m(c)
        ) as Pro where Pro.Rolename in
        (SELECT * from RoleTable)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join this table like:

```
select p.*
from Process as p
outer apply p.WorkflowXML.nodes('/Tasks/Task[@type="start"]/TaskUsers/TaskUser') as  m(c)
INNER JOIN RoleTable r 
    ON r.Rolename = m.c.value('@RoleName','varchar(max)')
```